# Accessibility testing in android apps

Tags: accessibility

I have seen many tools or browser plugins available for web accessibility testing. But how do people check accessibility for android apps?

Answer (score 0):

Available options:

1- use accessibility [Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.auditor)

2- enable A11y [checks](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/accessibility-checking#enable-checks) for your UI espresso testing
AccessibilityChecks.enable()

3- use talkback to manually verify your app behavior.